# Oracle 11g Sql loader performance issue

Tags: oracle, performance, sql-loader

I have two unix servers like (server1, server2), Currently I am loading the files (record count for 1 file - 124536) to database in server1 by using sql loader. It is loading within two minutes. But I have migrated my code to server2 in this server for loading same file it is taking almost 40 minutes.

Could anybody please help me on this?

Comment: So what is different about the second server? Different spec? More concurrent usage? Slower discs or interconnects? Is the drive where you run SQL Loader local to the database?

Comment: How can we check these details like " Different spec? More concurrent usage? Slower discs or interconnects? Is the drive where you run SQL Loader local to the database?"  i am not able to find this .

Comment: You need to ask a DBA or sysadmin.